# Write incrementing value to all files matching a filename in subdirectories

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find

I'm trying to do a number of test runs on an algorithm and as such have a number of directories containing exactly the same data (subdirectories and files) to be run on a cluster. I would like all of these directories to contain a file called `randomseed.txt` which contains a unique integer. Currently, the randomseed files exist, but contain the same integer: 1. Is there a bash script I could use, or a variation of `find` that I could use to achieve this simply?

My idea was something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i VAR
VAR=1

find . -type f -name "randomseed.txt" -execdir VAR=$VAR+1 | $VAR > randomseed.txt \;

echo $VAR
echo done
```

but I'm not entirely sure how or if I can do something like this with `-exec` or `-execdir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
/bin/bash
x=1
find . -name 'randomseed.txt' | \
while IFS= read file ; do
  echo $x > "$file"
  x=$(($x+1))
done
```

`IFS=` is to prevent breaking on spaces in file path if they exist, probably will not happen in your case.

Piping results of find into the while loop `read` which assigns the value to `file` then runs loop body. `x=$(($x+1))` is your gross `x+=1`

Comment: You should quote `$file`, since that would break with spaces, other special characters, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `find`, you could turn on globstar to make shell globbing recursive.

```
 shopt -s globstar
```

`cd` to the parent directory of this structure, then to test (over)writing the files:

```
n=0; for i in **; do [[ -d "$i" ]] && echo "echo $((++n)) >" "$i"/randomseed.txt; done
```

You can see it's going to write a file in each directory at every level. You can then remove the extra echo to actually write the files:

```
n=0; for i in **; do [[ -d "$i" ]] && echo $((++n)) > "$i"/randomseed.txt; done
```

You might want to unset globstar when done:

```
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: The only problem with this for me is that randomseed.txt exists (with other directories) at a depth of 2  and I don't want randomseeds in all the other directories (it wouldn't actually effect anything but would be extra junk). I just edited your script to point to the specific directory where the randomseed.txt is within the structure and this worked great! I also didn't need to use globstar for this instance. Thanks!

Comment: @onyinyang oh I see - I couldn't tell that from your description :) It was a pleasure, thanks for asking a nice question :)

Answer (score 3):

Run a loop creating numbers and have the `find`-executed command read those numbers:

```
for ((i = 1; ; i++)); do echo $i; done | 
  find . -type f -name "randomseed.txt" -exec sh -c 'read i; echo $i > "$1"' _ {} \;
```

You can also use `seq`:

```
seq 1 inf | find . -type f -name "randomseed.txt" -exec sh -c 'read i; echo $i > "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this to change directory names in a similar way! Thanks for the lead, though it wasn't what your answer was originally intended for!